# Bundling: Difference between rendering of script with optimizations on and off

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrease

I'm using ASP.NET 4.5 MVC4 and I've setup a bundling of css and javascript files with custom made bundles that worked before.

I've made the bundles myself, because the load order is important.

Somehow it stopped working. I did an update to the latest WebGrease (1.3.0) recently. Could that be a problem?

The strange thing is it works when I set `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations` to false. But when I set it to true, I get js errors.

Answer (score 0):

Which js errors do you get? The main difference with the property `EnableOptimization` to `on` (see this [page](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)) is that it concatenates all your scripts and minifies them.